# Как напечатать отсортированный словарь?

Tags: python

Есть словарь

```
d = {'my?': 1, 'hello': 2, 'friend?': 1, 'you?': 1}
```

У меня не получается его отсортировать.
Как вывести значения этого словаря в отсортированном порядке?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: что значит "отсортированный"? Что сортировать: ключи в словаре, только значения или сортировать пары ключ-значение все вместе?

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно получить отсортированный список пар ключ-значение, то можно использовать функцию `sorted`:

```
sorted(d.items())
# [('friend?', 1), ('hello', 2), ('my?', 1), ('you?', 1)]
```

Сортировку можно выполнить произвольным способом, например, по сортировать сначала по значению, потом по ключу:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))
# [('friend?', 1), ('my?', 1), ('you?', 1), ('hello', 2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Словарь в *Python* отсортировать нельзя, поскольку он представляет собой принципиально несортируемую сущность. Словарь реализован на основе хэш-таблиц, поэтому даже при упорядоченном добавлении элементов в словарь, их порядок может измениться.

Чтобы "пробежаться" по словарю в порядке возрастания ключей, нужно получить какую-либо другую структуру, с помощью которой и осуществлять вывод.

Например, можно сделать так:

```
for key in sorted(d.keys()):
    print(key + " : " + d[key])
```